# Access inline object in InlineModelAdmin form

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

I have such a problem: I want to limit foreign key choices in inline model admin, but I want to do this based on some values specified in this inline object.

How can I access inline object (not parent object) inside InlineModelAdmin methods (specifically in `formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs)`)?

Answer (score 6):

You **cannot access** to an inline object inside any InlineModelAdmin methods.

The only way is to use a custom ModelForm which receive `instance` when is initialized. Pay attention that `extra` forms to create new inline object receive and "empty" `instance` (pk=None).

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin, TabularInline

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            # do what you want with inline object instance

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = "__all__"

class QuestionInline(TabularInline):
    model = Question
    form = QuestionForm

class CategoryAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Category
    inlines = [QuestionInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. Change "YourModelAdmin", "target_field", "your_custom_condition" and '...' with your proper values.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
    field = super(YourModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name == 'target_field':
        if request and your_custom_condition:
            field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(...)
    return field
```

Comment: My question is about one step further: inside `formfield_for_foreigkey` and appropriate `db_field` I want to filter possible options according to **current inline model object**. So how can I access this object?

Comment: @andrzejdoro Could you figure that out? I am having similar issue. Your solution might help me. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did't find solution. I'm afraid that it is impossible to access this values. But if you figure it out please let me know.